# Docker ARG command building Google Managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-managed-vm

Is possible pass arguments building a managed vm to use 'ARG' Docker command?.

In Dockerfile sets default value...
**ARG** env="dev"

Building Docker container I can change this value...
docker build -t test/app **--build-arg** env=pr .

I have two environments and I want deploy the managed vm with different configuration files in Dockerfile build process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this isn't currently supported.  All of our docker build stuff right now is kind of magically integrated.  There are a few options here, though none of them are quite what you're looking for.

You can build your docker container locally, push it to gcr.io, and then use the --image-url flag on [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/deploy).

In the next few weeks, we're going to start using our [container builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/) service by default for docker builds with Managed VMs.  While we don't have a plan right now to expose the setting, there's a config setting that allows you to define [environment variables via the container builder API](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Source).  It's going to be easier to support something like this in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's 2019 and it seems it's still not possible to specify `--build-arg` when invoking `gcloud app deploy` :/